# How to show error message when internet/server/vpn is not available

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, ajax4jsf

I have a code something goes like this;

```
<a4j:commandLink 
actionListener="#{controller.validate}"
onclick="showFadeLoadingImg();"
oncomplete="confirmOperation();}"
value="#{actionItem.actionDisplayName}"
reRender="text1,text2">
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Here, when my VPN is down, my oncomplete event has jscript function confirmOperation(), which gets executed and undesired output from that function is being displayed. But, what I ultimately want is, when I click the button, I want to check whether I can able to connect to the server(VPN/internet enabled or not), and if not I have to show some error message like 'Unable to reach server' or else, can I redirect the page to login page?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the server on validate() method,If you can't connect to the server, you can record the information,and then you can user you jscript function confirmOperation() to display this infomation.